# What is the best way to unload a PHP array into html table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to print customerdata via PHP (in table). Only I run into the problem that it must come from two different web stores (a dual array). The first webshop has a customer and the other two.

This code is retrieved by a connection via the woocommerce API.
Firstly I connect to the database getting all "Woocommerce Stores"

```
$webshops = DB::table('webshops')->get();
$costumerdata = array();
```

Then I loop trought the data to get all data

```
foreach ($webshops as $webshop => $value) {
    $wc_api = new WC_API_Client($value->WEBSHOP_CONSUMER_KEY, $value->WEBSHOP_CONSUMER_SECRET, $value->WEBSHOP_URL);
    // array_push($costumerlist, $wc_api->get_customers());
    foreach ($wc_api->get_customers() as $costumer) {  
        array_push($costumerdata, $costumer);
    }
}
```

When I throw a DD over the data,

```
dd($costumerdata);
```

The next data is returned from the script. Now I want to put this array in an HTML / PHP list. How do I turn a whole list of all the customers in a table (I think I do not the loop properly).

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#252 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"created_at": "2018-11-22T14:29:01Z"
      +"email": "TheScruffieSpadexMuffin@gmail.cop"
      +"first_name": "Bernardo"
      +"last_name": "Mcscrufflemuffle"
      +"username": "thescruffiespadexmuffin"
      +"role": "customer"
      +"last_order_id": 21
      +"last_order_date": "2018-11-22T14:29:01Z"
      +"orders_count": 1
      +"total_spent": "0.00"
      +"avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/57918972c32605a2acc4d15771f09f69?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
      +"billing_address": {#253 ▶}
      +"shipping_address": {#254 ▶}
    }
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#245 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"created_at": "2018-11-22T17:48:21Z"
      +"email": "info@xxx-it.nl"
      +"first_name": "Bladieblabla"
      +"last_name": "Vla"
      +"username": "info"
      +"role": "customer"
      +"last_order_id": 28
      +"last_order_date": "2018-11-23T10:08:06Z"
      +"orders_count": 2
      +"total_spent": "0.00"
      +"avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ba4da010e0ff01978cdf0d3e176dfcea?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
      +"billing_address": {#256 ▶}
      +"shipping_address": {#257 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#258 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"created_at": "2018-11-23T10:10:48Z"
      +"email": "asdaasd@xxx-it.nl"
      +"first_name": "Lyla"
      +"last_name": "Futurama"
      +"username": "asdaasd"
      +"role": "customer"
      +"last_order_id": 29
      +"last_order_date": "2018-11-23T10:10:49Z"
      +"orders_count": 1
      +"total_spent": "0.00"
      +"avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/a4626c2ac8236e09229e3599d0302c84?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
      +"billing_address": {#259 ▶}
      +"shipping_address": {#260 ▶}
    }
  ]
]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You should look at Laravel's collections for this use case. You can use the `each()` method to loop through items and the `map()` method to return just the data you need.

Comment: Whats you meaning with "unload into html"? You can iterate the values at your template and just echo some values?

Comment: Looks like you need another inner foreach to loop over `$customer`. As it seems like `$wc_api->get_customers()` returns an array of customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need another inner foreach to loop over `$customer`. As it seems like `$wc_api->get_customers()` returns an array of customers

```
foreach ($webshops as $webshop => $value) {
    $wc_api = new WC_API_Client($value->WEBSHOP_CONSUMER_KEY, $value->WEBSHOP_CONSUMER_SECRET, $value->WEBSHOP_URL);
    foreach ($wc_api->get_customers() as $costumers) {  
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $costumerdata[] = $customer;
        }
    }
}
```

> Also its more efficient to do `$costumerdata[] = $costumer;` than use `array_push()` if you are only adding one item to the array at a time, as you remove the overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

the quick'n lazy way is to just throw it out there formatted by printf or JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, and just remember to html-encode the output, eg

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities(print_r($costumerdata,true), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
echo '</pre>';
```

or

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities(json_encode($costumerdata,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION | JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
echo '</pre>';
```

wouldn't surprise me if laravel has something fancy built-in to do the same, but i'm not aware of it. (and i don't know laravel in general, but i know PHP.)

ps, JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS is first introduced in PHP7.1, if your code needs to be compatible with older versions of PHP, you should add a

```
if(!defined("JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS")){
    define("JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS",0);
}
```

before using it. (prior to 7.1, JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS was always on by default and impossible to disable)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am still stick at one thing. How can a loop throught the data so I get the correct data back using a for loop